# Creating wrapper library to be dynamically linked

Tags: c

I know that every function of another library can be wrapped into another one in my library using dlopen and dlsym and calling pointer I got. I even know that I can create something like jump table and then implement something like `void __declspec(naked) func (void) { __asm{jmp[dlopened_addr]}; }`. That is not a problem. The problem is that I can not re-export other symbols that can be dlopened, like pointers to structures used in runtime. Is there any solution for that? Maybe modifiing runtime symbols table or relocation table? Any solution for that.
P.s. it is needed for using functions dlopened by linker of another libc (like https://github.com/mittorn/custom-linker).

Comment: You can export pointers from your wrapper, or better, add a function that returns a pointer.

Comment: It is not something I need. I want to make it something like ABI adaptation layer. And library wrappers should behave just like target libraries. I know that probably solution will not be portable but I still need it.